# Integer promotion unsigned in c++

Tags: c++, unsigned-integer

```
int main() {
    unsigned i = 5;
    int j = -10; 
    double d = i + j;
    long l = i + j;
    int k = i + j;
    std::cout << d << "\n";     //4.29497e+09
    std::cout << l << "\n";     //4294967291
    std::cout << k << "\n";     //-5
    std::cout << i + j << "\n"; //4294967291
}
```

I believe `signed int` is promoted to `unsigned` before doing the arithmetic operators.
While `-10` is converted to unsigned `unsigned integer underflow` (*is this the correct term??*) will occur and after addition it prints `4294967291`.

Why this is not happening in the case of `int k` which print `-5`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The process of doing the arithmetic operator involves a conversion to make the two values have the same type. The name for this process is finding the *common type*, and for the case of `int` and `unsigned int`, the conversions are called [*usual arithmetic conversions*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic).  The term [*promotion*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) is not used in this particular case.

In the case of `i + j`, the `int` is converted to `unsigned int`, by adding `UINT_MAX + 1` to it.  So the result of `i + j` is `UINT_MAX - 4`, which on your system is `4294967291`.

You then store this value in various data types; the only output that needs further explanation is `k`.  The value `UINT_MAX - 4` cannot fit in `int`. This is called *out-of-range assignment* and the resulting value is implementation-defined. On your system it apparently assigns the `int` value which has the same representation as the `unsigned int` value.

Answer (score 1):

`j` will be *converted* to `unsigned int` before addition, and this happens in all your `i + j`. A quick experiment.

In the case of `int k = i + j`. As in the case of your implementation and mine, `i + j` produces: `4294967291`. `4294967291` is larger than `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`, the behavior is going to be implementation defined. Why not try assigning `4294967291` to an `int`?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int k = 4294967291;
    std::cout << k << std::endl;
}
```

Produces:

```
-5
```

As seen [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e8ec20608701843)