# What happened to operator '+'?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm using Qt Creator (Community Version) to build a software, which can read data from a device with RS-485 connection.

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. Please check this picture:

[image: Operator+]

Everything's fine until `iBienSuCo1 += result[18]`. I don't know where the data comes from.
Is there any ideas in this situation?

Comment: What do you mean? you `+=` your variable.

Comment: What is `iBienSuCo1`?! Also, are you checking for the range safely before accessing `result[18]`?!

Comment: Sorry for that. `iBienSuCo1` is `unsigned int`, `result[18]` is `char`.

Comment: @HoangTran: What is your expected output??

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. And don't ever paste pictures of code and errors full of text, paste the text itself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer promotion unsigned in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42200610/integer-promotion-unsigned-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result[17]` is a `char` value of 0x00.

`result[18]` is a `char` value of 0xC0.

Your compiler implements `char` as a signed type, so the compiler will sign-extend a `char` value to a `signed int` before assigning/adding it to an `unsigned int` variable. The high bit of 0xC0 is 1, so the extended bits are filled with 1s, producing 0xFFFFFFC0, which is 4294967232 when interpreted as an unsigned integer, and is -64 when interpreted as a signed integer.

To do what you are trying to do, use this instead:

```
iBienSuCo1 = (unsigned char)result[17];
iBienSuCo1 = (iBienSuCo1 << 8) | (unsigned char)result[18];
```

By casting `char` to `unsigned char` (not to `unsigned int`!) before extension, the compiler will zero-extend the values (the extended bits are filled with 0s) instead of sign-extend.  That will produce the result of 0x000000C0 that you are looking for.

[live demo](https://ideone.com/2MVs0q)

Comment: I fixed the problem in the same way as you mentioned above yesterday. Thanks and good day.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding of your question,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned int i = -1;
    ++i;
    i += -64;
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

so before `i` was added to -64, that is your `iBieSucol` which is unsigned int and its value is UINT_MAX (for 32 bit). Then you subtract it by 64.

Comment: what do you want? i don't see anything wrong

Comment: Understood. I changed my code to this:
`iBienSuCo1 = (unsigned int)result[17];
 iBienSuCo1 = (iBienSuCo1 << 8) | (unsigned int)result[18];`
But it's still the same.

Comment: try to write these numbers in binary format u  will know why  you get that

Comment: I want to copy data from `result[17]` and `result[18]` to `iBienSuCo1`. `result[17]` is High Byte, `result[18]` is Low Byte.